# Airflow SqlToS3Operator has unwanted an index in the beginning

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

Recent airflow-providers-amazon has deprecated MySQLToS3Operator and introduced SqlToS3Operator and now it is adding an index column in the beginning of the CSV dump.

For example, if I run the following

```
sql_to_s3_task = SqlToS3Operator(
    task_id="sql_to_s3_task",
    sql_conn_id=conn_id_name,
    query="SELECT created_at, score FROM my_table",
    s3_bucket=bucket_name,
    s3_key=key,
    replace=True,
)
```

The S3 file has something like this:

```
,created_at,score
1,2023-01-01,5
2,2023-01-02,6
```

The output seems to be a direct dump from Pandas. How can I remove this unwanted preceding index column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operator uses pandas DataFrame under the hood.
You should use `pd_kwargs`. It allows you to pass arguments to include in DataFrame `.to_parquet()`, `.to_json()` or `.to_csv()`.

Since your output is `csv` the relevant [pandas.DataFrame.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) parameters are:

```
header: bool or list of str, default True
Write out the column names. If a list of strings is given it is assumed to be aliases for the column names.

index: bool, default True
Write row names (index).
```

Thus you can do:

```
sql_to_s3_task = SqlToS3Operator(
    task_id="sql_to_s3_task",
    sql_conn_id=conn_id_name,
    query="SELECT created_at, score FROM my_table",
    s3_bucket=bucket_name,
    s3_key=key,
    replace=True,
    file_format="csv",
    pd_kwargs={"index": False, "header": False},
)
```